# GDB locate TLS variable from core

Tags: linux, gdb, reverse-engineering, coredump

In debugging a core file, I can find the `pthread_specific` data but I have not found a way to access `__thread` data such as `errno`.

The access is via `%fs:0x0` register and I can disassemble `__errno_location` to find its relative address from `%fs:0x0` but I don't see a way to resolve it on a per thread basis as it seems like the base `%fs` value is not available to GDB.

Example:

```
Dump of assembler code for function __errno_location:
   0x00007fefa83911f0 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00007fefa83911f1 <+1>: mov    0x206d90(%rip),%rax        # 0x7fefa8597f88
   0x00007fefa83911f8 <+8>: add    %fs:0x0,%rax
   0x00007fefa8391201 <+17>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00007fefa8391204 <+20>:    pop    %rbp
   0x00007fefa8391205 <+21>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Is there a way to find out what the value of `%fs:0x0` would be for the current thread?

The `info registers` command shows only this for the segment registers:

```
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
```

libc version: 2.17
libc.so.6 debug not currently installed
GDB version: GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1

Comment: Please edit your question and supply version of GDB and GLIBC you are using, as well as whether `libc6-dbg` or similar glibc debug info package is installed.

Comment: Do you have any further suggestion on how to locate the thread locals from the core?

Comment: I added the information missing about libc debug. I would have to dig and see if we have the corresponding debug file available if it is essential. I have been able to locate the pthread structure roughly by searching for tid/pid. When debugging a live process, gdb will print the pthread_t address for the frame, but the same doesn't happen when inspecting a core file

Comment: I would try to install the `libc6-dbg` package as the first step. GDB may just start working, and even if it doesn't, locating the data would be much easier when debug info is available.

Comment: I've added the libc debug. What made some things work is that the libthread_db was not loading correctly. But I still see errors like this when trying to access a TLS variable such as errno:

Cannot find thread-local storage for Thread 0x7f0ee94ae700 (LWP 4585), shared library /lib64/libc.so.6: